# Dailymotion API : Video is not retrieved

Tags: dailymotion-api

I have started recently to use Dailymotion API in my application. So, I am really new with it. 
Sorry if my question has already been resolved.

I have faced a little problem when retrieving videos using this API.

In fact, when I call the URL : api.dailymotion.com/video/x37692p, the video seems to be available. But when using : api.dailymotion.com/videos?ids=x37692p, the result is {"page":1,"limit":10,"explicit":false,"total":0,"has_more":false,"list":[]}, which means the video couldn't be found.

Can you please clarify the reason of this behavior?

I need to work with the URL api.dailymotion.com/videos and make sure it returns all the existing videos in DM.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

if a video can't be found in the listings, you can check the following:

- is the video public or private? Check https://developer.dailymotion.com/api/internal#private-public for more info
- is the video explicit? if it is, you need to pass the `family_filter=false` global parameter to list explicit videos along with non explicit ones (https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#global-parameters). Also check this  documentation section https://developer.dailymotion.com/api/internal#family-filter
- other idea is that the video may have been flaggued as spam, this is why it's not listed

In your case, given the content of the video, this behavior may be due to spam detection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to know if it is possible to list videos flagged as spams in my website. What is the field used in the DM API to identify spams ?

Comment: you can't list spam videos: the flag videos are withdrawn from API listing as they are spam :)